# is MDBG (Managed debugger) for .NET free to use for commercial purposes?

Tags: .net, debugging, mdbg

i am making a project. for that i need to use a debugger. obsly MDBG is my first choice. but as i downloaded the sample and read the eula. it states that

> You may not use the software for commercial software hosting services.

but this eula is for

> MICROSOFT CLR MANAGED DEBUGGER (MDBG) SOURCE SAMPLE

so my ques is can i use it or cant i?

Comment: Why is MDBG 'obsly' your first choice? VS Express has a great debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You may not use the software for commercial software hosting services.

That was a boilerplate phrase that appeared in all Microsoft EULAs several years ago.  I haven't seen it lately, but MDBG dates from the time that this phrase was common. The specific exclusion is that you can't use Microsoft tools or code samples to build a web site and then re-sell the service to 3rd parties.  Nothing particularly nefarious, at the time they probably thought that web hosting was an important business segment for them and they didn't want to have to compete with anybody using their own tools to build such a hosting service.

Take note of this when you plan to create your own kind of GoDaddy with a traceable way for anybody to see that you used the MDBG sample code to run your service.  The intersection of Microsoft still caring about that with the odds that MDBG will actually be useful in a hosting service is sufficiently small to not worry about this.  And of course, never take legal advice from a programmer's Q+A site :)

Comment: what u mean here is that i cant compile using MDBG. when iam actly charging users of my service for compiling..

Comment: Well, no, MDBG is a debugger, not a compiler.  But you get the gist of it.

Comment: yeah sry ...ijust meant i cant debug using MDBG when iam actly charging for debugging.

Comment: thankx for ans dude.. i thought .net sdk is free to use and cuz it is a part of that. it shud also be.. with it it actly is very tough to find EULA for diff sdks of .net.. do u have any links for that too?

Comment: Well, yes, it is free, you don't have to pay anybody to use it.  But that's just free as in beer, you must still agree with the license terms.  Exact same thing with a GPL license.  Also free but pretty strict rules on how you use the free software.  Or this answer for that matter.  You can copy it anywhere you like and modify it as you see fit.  But you must agree to the CC license that covers this answer.  You can freely copy but *must* provide attribution when you do so.

Answer (score 1):

MDbg is part of the .NET Framework SDK, which is free.

The MDbg sample is the source code, which aparently you are not allowed to integrate in 'commercial software hosting services.' You are still allowed to use MDbg for debugging any project.

VS has a great debugger. VS Express is free and is quite powerful. You shouldn't have to use a commandline debugger.

Comment: for use in commercial purposes?

Comment: i cant install vs where i need to do all this.. :(

Comment: Where? A customer's machine? Why can't you use VS? And AFAIK, .NET SDK is free for use on commercial apps.